# Do I have three levels of content, or can I reduce it to two?

Tags: gui-design, menu, information-architecture, hierarchy

I'm working on overhauling an interface that has two clearly defined levels of navigation, and then one murky level. Clicking on the first level will reveal sub-options which correspond to that initial heading. Mousing over these sub-options will reveal vertical menus containing further pages per sub-option.

The problem is, the sub-options themselves do not meaningfully connect to any of their menu "children". In fact, clicking on one of these menu headings will take you to an entirely different location. In an attempt to redesign this system into a tabbed interface with an always-displayed horizontal outlining of all navigation links, I find myself unsure how to solve this problem.

Do I morph the second-level choices (the previous menu headings) into more general pages (e.g. Programs and Assessments instead of SpecificDepartmentHere's Program Activity) with unfortunately minimal display in the content pane before the user reaches the third level? Or do I promote the children to the second level, running the risk of overloading a user with choices?

I feel as though the first option is best for a new user, but the experienced ones might soon find it as another screen to click through before reaching that last level.

I apologize if this is hard to envision, or if my language is unrefined to adequately describe the situation. I'm definitely green at this.

Comment: Perhaps some screenshots/sketches would be useful? By "do not meaningfully connect" do you mean they are not children but related, or that they are neither children nor related? Is it similar to how [Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/) works: you click UK, and the links to 'Business', 'Health', etc are presented as children, even though they are not.

Comment: They are not children, but very tangentially related.

I apologize for my lack of screenshots at this time.

Comment: I'm having a hell of a time trying to visualize your problem. I just can't get my head around it, so I'm sorry but I can't be of any help. Please try and add some images describing the current situation, the problem you're trying to solve, and a possible solution you already tried.

Comment: Seconding all these guys. Seriously, dude. Give us sketches.

Comment: Even though you can't post them directly, if you upload screen shots and post the links, a moderator can edit your post to show them inline.

Comment: Perhaps just type out list of the first level and sub level navigation links as you described? Might be easier if we know exactly what type of contents you are trying to organize.

Comment: if you cannot post screenshots, go to "Edit" post, click on "create mock-up". This will open Blasmiq where you can draw it out for us.

Comment: It sounds like you have a general problem of how to structure your page's content. Maybe it would help you if you drew up a list of ALL pages and then try to organize them into groups and see what kind of structure you can come up with if you completely disregard how they are organized at the moment.

Comment: at least, you need to give rough number of items (sections) in each level. Because it is way too much difference in between 2+2+3 and 2+10+40 solution

Answer (score 1):

**See where your application fits in the different [navigation patterns](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/website-architecture/ia-models/).**

Specifically, consider questions like this:

- **Are all items at the third level similar?**  For example, every
  question could have many comments.  This would imply the same
  structure would be used at the third level.
- **Are the items at the third level different depending on the second level?**  For example,
  one second level item could be products to browse while another second
  level could be the company contact info.  This would imply the third
  level should be implemented differently depending on context, and may
  not need to be part of the main navigation for consistency.

**If you can't see it clearly, use [card sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_sorting).**  Try setting the cards in front of someone unfamiliar with the application and see how they group the items.  You may find a pattern that you didn't previously see.